# Unable to get index of an object in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I thought if I maintain the original reference than I would simply get the index

```
const selected = {id: "abcd123", quantity: "5"};
const location = [
  {id: "abcd123", quantity: "3"},
  {id: "abcd1234", quantity: "3"},
];
const filterLocation = location.filter(loc => loc.id === selected.id);
console.log(location.indexOf(filterLocation));
```

I expect it would log `0` but it always return `-1`. How it actually works?

Comment: Why are you calling `.indexOf(..)` in your `console.log` statement?

Comment: I want to get the index of the `selected`

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) doesn't return an index, it returns a new array with all the filtered elements. In your case `filterLocation` is an array with one element. Try `console.log( filterLocation );`

Answer (score 1):

```
  const selected = {id: "abcd123", quantity: "5"};
  const location = [
    {id: "abcd123", quantity: "3"},
    {id: "abcd1234", quantity: "3"},
  ];
 const filterLocation = location.filter(loc => loc.id === selected.id);

 console.log(location.findIndex(value => value.id === filterLocation[0].id )));
```

`filter` return a new array. So, you just need access to that value `filtered` in this example

change `indexOf` for `findIndex`. `location` is an array of objects so you need to iterate all the array again for recover the index. Sure, it's just for this example, also you could recover the index in the same `filter` operation.

```
 console.log(location.findIndex(value => value.id === filterLocation[0].id )));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, *indexOf* is trying to find a string ("abcd123") in an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `filterLocation` does not include any object identical to the `location`. It includes the only object with the same `id` field but the `quantity` field is different. Secondly the `indexOf` method does not work properly for non-scalar arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake

I think I should switch to `findIndex` instead of `indexOf`.

```
const selected = {id: "abcd123", quantity: "5"};
const location = [
 {id: "abcd123", quantity: "3"},
 {id: "abcd1234", quantity: "3"},
];
const filterLocation = location.filter(loc => loc.id === selected.id);
console.log(location.findIndex(loc => loc.id === selected.id));
```

Then I would get the specified index that I need.

Comment: If this is your answer, you should write it as a proper answer and accept it (something like *"instead of indexOf, use findIndex as follows:*).